# Trim date from file name using powershell or cmd

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

How do you trim the date from a text file. For example, I have multiple files like:

- test_20091011.txt
- try_20091011.txt
- fold_20091011.txt

I would like to change into:

- test.txt
- try.txt
- fold.txt

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code should work assuming the text file name format doesn't change, as in, it's always the last 9 characters you need to remove.  This code assumes the txt files are in the folder C:\folder

```
    $filelist = (get-childitem c:\folder | Where-Object {$_.mode -match "a"} | foreach-object {$_.name})
foreach ($file in $filelist)
    {
        $len = $file.length
        $newname = $file.substring(0,$len -13)
        $newname = $newname + '.txt'
        Rename-Item C:\folder\$file $newname
        clear-variable newname, len
    }
```

Comment: Thank You so so so much, can you explain in detail as to what each of these are doing? I am noob at this and learning.

Comment: Glad it worked for you :)

I'll try to explain in the limited space they give us.

$filelist is a container that I put all the txt file names into, using get-childitem.  GCI gets file info for files in whatever folder you specify.  The where-object I use to limit GCI to only finding files, skipping subfolders($_.mode -match "a").  foreach-object {$_.name} gets the name of each file and adds it to the $filelist container.


Then the foreach loops through each file in the $filelist container.  $len gets and holds the files char length.

Comment: $newname creates and contains the files name with the date trimmed off ( you must -13 and not -9 to take the '.txt' extension chars into account).  The second $newname line re-adds the .txt extension, making the $newname container complete, as in, it now holds the file name with the date stripped out and formated correctly.

Rename-Item is a builtin powershell cmdlet (like get-childitem) where you can rename items.  It loops through each $file in the $filename container, changing all the names.

Comment: If you type 'get-childitem c:\folder' (no quotes) into the powershell window, you'll understand a litte more also.

Check out this page if you're just getting started.  However, there are a ton of great PoSH sites out there.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee221100.aspx

Comment: Also keep in mind, this script will strip the last 9 chars out of the name of EVERY file in the folder, not just .txt files.  And if it runs into a file with a name of 9 or less chars, it will error out.

Comment: Oh...and one final thought, keep in mind, not only will this strip the last 9 chars out of the name of every file, it will then make every file a .txt file.  :)

Answer (score 0):

The answer for this will change subtly depending on the type of naming pattern, but in your case, you can accomplish this with a script like this:

```
Get-ChildItem | 
    Where-Object {
        <# 
        Multiple Assignment in PowerShell.  
        $beforeUnderbar will have your name, 
        $AfterUnderBar will have the data, and 
        $extension will have the extension. 
        All from one little -split  
        If you start throwing random other files in there, it will barf.
        #>
        $beforeUnderbar, $afterUnderBar, $extension = ($_.Name -split "[_.]")
        if ($afterUnderBar -and $afterUnderBar.Length -eq 8 -and $afterUnderBar -as [int]) {
        "$beforeUnderBar.$extension"
        }
    }
```

That script should give you what you want from files that match your naming convention.

Comment: hello thanks for your response, but I get this error Missing statement block after if ( condition ).
At line:13 char:9
+          <<<< "$beforeUnderBar.$extension"
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingStatementBlock  here is a sample out of a group of files, EMPLOYEE_SKILL_20110519.TXT, I wanna just trim 9 characters from the back. which means the new file will be EMPLOYEE_SKILL.TXT

Comment: That would be because I forgot to put them in.  Sorry, I was typing out an ad-hoc solution.  I added the brackets to the sample.